# How can I save the user data from Cordova Facebook auth to users table in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the user data's from Facebook for a mobile app. In Front End we are using angular Cordova plugin to handle Facebook auth login. We are getting the user info such as name, email, gender, image. My question is how do I save those datas in my database.

routes.rb

```
resources :users
post 'user/facebook' => 'users#facebook'
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :name, :uid, :provider, :gender, :oauth_token

 def self.fbreg(auth)
  user = User.create(name: auth[:name],
    email: auth[:email],        
    provider: auth[:provider],
    uid: auth[:uid],
    gender: auth[:gender],
    image: auth[:image],
    oauth_token: auth[:oauth_token]
   )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user
 end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def facebook    
  params[:user][:provider] = "facebook"    
  @user = User.where("uid = ? OR email = ?",params[:user][:uid],params[:user][:email]).first
  if @user.present?      
  sign_in @user
  return render :json => {:success => true, :token => @user.oauth_token, :user => @user}
  else
  @reg = User.fbreg(params[:user])      
  sign_in @reg
  return render :json => {:success => true, :token => @reg.oauth_token}
 end
end
```

and here I was stuck, Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how exactly you are stuck?

Comment: @TobiasSchoknecht we are doing the auth in the frontend, each time users runs the app it will check the availability of the userId in the app (in localStorage), if it's not exist it will send it to backend, as a safety measure we will check if the userId exist if not we will create a new instance of the user in user table. and send back a 200 and the user object to front end to store in localStorage.
I am really get stuck with getting the data from facebook. I really unaware how to do this and I am not sure whether I am moving in right way

Comment: Nothing you provide has anything to do with getting the data from facebook though. Your current approach rests entirely on having the frontend do all the heavy lifting, i.e. the facebook API calls, which should be handled by the plugin you mentioned. The ruby code should work the way you wrote it, assuming you actually send the data to the server.

Comment: I assume your issue is more of a nature regarding: is there a better way?